# LLVM IR: <N x i1> vector instructions ordering causing different results

Tags: llvm, code-generation, llvm-ir

I have been using LLVM as a backend for my compiler (I'm not using the LLVM libraries but my own to generate the necessary IR for numerous reasons). At the moment, I am implementing vector operations. Comparisons of vectors emit vectors of booleans `<N x i1>` and these are causing me problems.

To access vector elements, I have been using `extractelement` and `insertelement` however, I am getting some weird behaviour when I execute these instructions in a different orders. The code examples below have the same instructions and should be logically the same. Version 1 outputs `BAA` while Version 2 outputs `BAB`. Version 2 is the logically correct version but I cannot figure out why version 1 outputs the wrong version but has the exact same instructions, just in a different order.

***EDIT:*** A workaround to *solve* this problem is to pass the IR to `opt -mem2reg` and then compile the bitcode. This is *okay* but not useful for debugging and thus does not *solve* my problem.

### Version 1

```
; Version 1 - Generated by my naïve SSA generator
; Outputs: BAA (incorrect)
declare i32 @putchar(i32)

define void @main() {
entry:
    %0 = alloca <8 x i1>, align 8 ; v
    store <8 x i1> zeroinitializer, <8 x i1>* %0
    %1 = alloca <8 x i1>, align 8
    store <8 x i1> zeroinitializer, <8 x i1>* %1
    %2 = load <8 x i1>, <8 x i1>* %1, align 8
    %3 = insertelement <8 x i1> %2, i1 true, i64 0
    %4 = insertelement <8 x i1> %3, i1 false, i64 1
    %5 = insertelement <8 x i1> %4, i1 true, i64 2
    %6 = insertelement <8 x i1> %5, i1 false, i64 3
    %7 = insertelement <8 x i1> %6, i1 true, i64 4
    %8 = insertelement <8 x i1> %7, i1 false, i64 5
    %9 = insertelement <8 x i1> %8, i1 true, i64 6
    %10 = insertelement <8 x i1> %9, i1 false, i64 7
    store <8 x i1> %10, <8 x i1>* %0

    %11 = load <8 x i1>, <8 x i1>* %0, align 8
    %12 = extractelement <8 x i1> %11, i64 0
    %13 = zext i1 %12 to i32
    %14 = add i32 %13, 65 ; + 'A'
    %15 = call i32 @putchar(i32 %14)

    %16 = load <8 x i1>, <8 x i1>* %0, align 8
    %17 = extractelement <8 x i1> %16, i64 1
    %18 = zext i1 %17 to i32
    %19 = add i32 %18, 65 ; + 'A'
    %20 = call i32 @putchar(i32 %19)

    %21 = load <8 x i1>, <8 x i1>* %0, align 8
    %22 = extractelement <8 x i1> %21, i64 2
    %23 = zext i1 %22 to i32
    %24 = add i32 %23, 65 ; + 'A'
    %25 = call i32 @putchar(i32 %24)

    %26 = call i32 @putchar(i32 10) ; \n

    ret void
}
```

---

### Version 2

```
; Version 2 - Manually modified version of Version 1
; Outputs: BAB (correct)
declare i32 @putchar(i32)

define void @main() {
entry:
    %0 = alloca <8 x i1>, align 8 ; v
    store <8 x i1> zeroinitializer, <8 x i1>* %0
    %1 = alloca <8 x i1>, align 8
    store <8 x i1> zeroinitializer, <8 x i1>* %1
    %2 = load <8 x i1>, <8 x i1>* %1, align 8
    %3 = insertelement <8 x i1> %2, i1 true, i64 0
    %4 = insertelement <8 x i1> %3, i1 false, i64 1
    %5 = insertelement <8 x i1> %4, i1 true, i64 2
    %6 = insertelement <8 x i1> %5, i1 false, i64 3
    %7 = insertelement <8 x i1> %6, i1 true, i64 4
    %8 = insertelement <8 x i1> %7, i1 false, i64 5
    %9 = insertelement <8 x i1> %8, i1 true, i64 6
    %10 = insertelement <8 x i1> %9, i1 false, i64 7
    store <8 x i1> %10, <8 x i1>* %0

    %11 = load <8 x i1>, <8 x i1>* %0, align 8
    %12 = load <8 x i1>, <8 x i1>* %0, align 8
    %13 = load <8 x i1>, <8 x i1>* %0, align 8

    %14 = extractelement <8 x i1> %11, i64 0
    %15 = extractelement <8 x i1> %12, i64 1
    %16 = extractelement <8 x i1> %13, i64 2

    %17 = zext i1 %14 to i32
    %18 = zext i1 %15 to i32
    %19 = zext i1 %16 to i32

    %20 = add i32 %17, 65 ; + 'A'
    %21 = add i32 %18, 65 ; + 'A'
    %22 = add i32 %19, 65 ; + 'A'

    %23 = call i32 @putchar(i32 %20)
    %24 = call i32 @putchar(i32 %21)
    %25 = call i32 @putchar(i32 %22)

    %26 = call i32 @putchar(i32 10) ; \n

    ret void
}
```

Comment: It is not impossible that this is a bug in LLVM. Version #2 and first call in #1 works probably because it can be optimized into constants. Try representing your bools as `i8` rather than `i1` - at least in memory. You can also try disabling vector instructions: `-mattr=-sse`.

Comment: You might consider asking this question on the llvm-dev mailing list (http://lists.llvm.org/mailman/listinfo/llvm-dev)

Comment: Banthar. It seems `-mattr=-sse` produces even weirder results (Still not what I expected). `<N x i1>` vectors seems to be packed in size, i.e. size of `<N x i1> = (1*N + 7)/8` bytes, which may be the root of the problems. Vectors of _regular size_ work as I expect and I have no problems with them but I cannot not use boolean vectors as they are the return type from comparison instructions.